# Can't append to txt file with a comma separator and linebreak

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a function (logger) that expects two arguments from another python file. one of the arguments is a user input: firstname, lastname, email and phone number. the logger function should write the user input into txt file with comma operator between all elements. Then the next time the user executes the code, it should append the new data to a newline, but does not do that. It continues with the same line. Can someone please take a look of what I am getting wrong. code is attached below:
import re

```
def firstnamechecker(firstname):
    firstEx = re.compile('[a-zA-Z]+$')
    if firstEx.match(firstname):
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
def lastnamechecker(lastname):
    lastnameEx = re.compile('[a-zA-Z]+$')
    if lastnameEx.match(lastname):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def emailchecker(email):
    emailEx = re.compile('[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$')
    if emailEx.match(email):
        return True
    else:
        return False
def phonenumberchecker(phonenumber):
    numEx = re.compile('\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$')
    if numEx.match(phonenumber):
        return True
    else:
        return False
  

def logger(logfile, data):
    filewrite = open(logfile, "a")
    data = data.splitlines()
    data[:-1:] = [x+',' for x in data[:-1:]]
    for item in data:
        filewrite.write(item)
    filewrite.close()
```

The code where the above code gets the information from is posted below:

```
import re
from checker import firstnamechecker, lastnamechecker, emailchecker,phonenumberchecker,logger

#lettersreg = re.compile('[a-zA-Z]+$')
#phonereg = re.compile('\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$')
#emailreg = re.compile('[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$')

ADDBOOKPATH = "addbookFinal.txt"
ADDBOOKDATA = "addbook.txt"

LOGGING = True
def firstname():
    firstname = input("put in your first name: ")
    if LOGGING:
        logger(ADDBOOKDATA, firstname)
    while not firstnamechecker(firstname):  
        firstname = input("put in your first name: ")
        if LOGGING:
            logger(ADDBOOKDATA, firstname)
    return firstname
    #lastname
def lastname():
    lastname = input("put in your last name: ")
    if LOGGING:
        logger(ADDBOOKDATA, lastname)
    while not lastnamechecker(lastname):  
        lastname = input("put in your last name: ")
        if LOGGING:
            logger(ADDBOOKDATA, lastname)
    return lastname
#email
def email():
    email = input("put in your email: ")
    if LOGGING:
        logger(ADDBOOKDATA, email)
    while not emailchecker(email):  
        email = input("put in your email: ")
        if LOGGING:
            logger(ADDBOOKDATA, email)
    return email
#phonenumber
def phonenumber():
    phonenumber = input("put in your phone number: ")
    if LOGGING:
        logger(ADDBOOKDATA, phonenumber)
    while not phonenumberchecker(phonenumber):  
        phonenumber = input("put in your phone number: ")
        if LOGGING:
            logger(ADDBOOKDATA, phonenumber)
    return phonenumber

def main():
    firstname()
    lastname()
    email()
    phonenumber()
main()
```

I updated the question and posted the code where the logger gets the information from. so basically, it should append like: firstname, lastname, email, phonenumber in one line and the next time the code is executed. it should write the new info into a newline in the same txt file.

Comment: "it should append the new data to a newline, but does not do that. It continues with the same line." Okay, *what part of the code is intended to cause the newlines?* Where is the code that writes to the file? What is it writing to the file? What do those values look like? Why are you surprised by the result?

Comment: (Hint: when you use `.write`, do you expect it to write to a new line each time automatically? Why? What does the documentation say?)

Comment: Incidentally: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You are [expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) to attempt to research and [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the problem yourself first, so that you can then show us enough, and only enough, code *to reproduce the problem*. Here, for example, there is no apparent relationship between `logger` and your various `checker`s, so it's unneeded; and there is no code that creates a value for `data`, so we cannot test it.

Comment: Thank you @KarlKnechtel I updated the question and posted the code where the logger gets the information from. so basically, it should append like: firstname, lastname, email, phonenumber in one line and the next time the code is executed. it should write the new info into a newline in the same txt file.

Comment: "and the next time the code is executed. it should write the new info into a newline in the same txt file." Okay, and *what part of the code is supposed to make that happen*? *Why* do you expect it to happen?

Comment: Separately: what steps did you take to try to understand the problem? For example, did you try putting `python write file on new line` into a search engine? What came up when you did that? Did it help? If not, why not?

Comment: I was thinking I could make that happen in the logger function I initially wrote something like: filewrite.write(data+',') but then it adds comma after the last element in that line and it also appends to the same line next time the code is executed. @KarlKnechtel

Comment: I notice that you keep writing "newline" as one word. I assume that you are familiar with the newline *character*, i.e. that you understand the special meaning of `"\n"` in code? Do you see how this might help you solve the problem?

Comment: no it does not because each time, each element will be broken into a new line like:  firstname "\n" lastname "\n" ..... and I don't want that to happen

Comment: What if you tried only writing a newline once, when the program starts?

Comment: how do I do that? can you post a solution if you have one please? @KarlKnechtel